# How can I use an OBS Virtual Camera in MS Teams?

Tags: macos, webcam, microsoft-teams, obs-studio

On previous versions of MS Teams I was able to select my virtual cam running from OBS. Since an update somehere in september I'm no longer able to select any virtual cameras in MS Teams. I've found multiple bug reports and complaints about it, but no solution.

Is there a way to still use my OBS camera in microsoft teams?

Versions I use:

- OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Teams: 1.3.00.26266
- OBS: 26.0.2
- OBS-mac-virtualcam: 1.2.0

Comment: It's still working for me. Just remember you need to be running OBS for the camera to be active

Comment: Yeah, I checked that. The virtual cam still works in Zoom and Chrome, so that's not where the problem is. I also found some commands that should make it work again: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/microsoft-teams-mac-os-client-is-not-recognizing/d9e863be-d9a4-4d03-a4b8-1b5c7df58828?auth=1&rtAction=1596554299553
But on that only made it look like it works for me. My teammates still don't see my virtual cam :(

Comment: My apologies - just realised you're on a Mac. I have one but not running OBS